# Cofactor-Trace Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a question regarding a lemma in the paper [Total Positivity and Toda Flow](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.514.9759&rep=rep1&type=pdf). $b_1, b_2, ..., b_p$ are column vectors of $B_p$. For a matrix $C$, the product $Cb_i$ is well defined. Prove that the following equality holds.

$$\sum_{j=1}^p det(b_1, ..., b_{j-1}, Cb_j, b_{j+1}, ..., b_p) = tr(C)detB_p$$

The author states that a proof will rely on the notion that $\sum_{i=1}^p a_{ij} A_{ik} = \delta_{jk} det(A)$ with $\delta$ being a Kronecker delta.

I feel that I already have an intuition for the special case when $b_j$ is an eigenvector of $C$; however, I fail to see the method required for a general proof. Could one successively factor out "pieces" of $C$, which will yield a sum or product of $tr(C)$?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a continuity argument, we may assume that $B$ is invertible. Let $X=B_p^{-1}CB_p$. Denote the $j$-th column of $X$ by $x_j$. Then $B_px_j=Cb_j$. Therefore, by Cramer's rule, the $j$-th entry of $x_j$ is given by
$$
\frac{\det(b_1,\ldots,b_j,Cb_j,b_{j+1},\ldots,b_p)}{\det(B_p)}.
$$
Since the $j$-th entry of $x_j$ is the $j$-th diagonal element $x_{jj}$ of $X$, we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(C)
=\operatorname{tr}(B_p^{-1}CB_p)
=\operatorname{tr}(X)
=\sum_{j=1}^px_{jj}
=\sum_{j=1}^p\frac{\det(b_1,\ldots,b_j,Cb_j,b_{j+1},\ldots,b_p)}{\det(B_p)}
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Yes, continuity may be assumed as one of the cases in the second theorem ensures that nonsingularity is preserved by the Toda Flow. (i.e., $det(A(0)) = det(A(t))$ will hold $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @JPwin That isn't what I mean by a "continuity argument". Since the subset of all invertible matrices is dense in the set of all square matrices, and both sides of the identity in question are continuous functions in the entries of $B_p$, if the identity holds for every invertible matrix $B_p$, then by passing $B_p$ to the limit, the identity also holds when $B_p$ is singular.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.